# label_mode for keras res_net regression

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, regression

I am currently working on a data science project where I try to predict prices based on images. I have my own dataset where every image has the price paid for it in its name. Now I tried to use the keras ResNet to run my price prediction but I am not quite sure how I should handle the labels.

I stored all the images in one folder and got the labels (price) by running a for-loop. Now I tried to split the dataset in training and validation with the code bellow:

```
img_height, img_width = 160,160
batch_size = 32
train_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
    data_dir,
    labels = labels,
    validation_split = 0.1,
    subset = "training",
    seed = 123,
    label_mode = "int",
    image_size = (img_height, img_width),
    batch_size = batch_size)

val_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
    data_dir,
    labels = labels,
    validation_split = 0.1,
    subset = "validation",
    seed = 123,
    label_mode = "int",
    image_size = (img_height, img_width),
    batch_size = batch_size)
```

This worked so far however I can only choose between the label_mode of int, categorical, binary and None but none of these options seems correct to me. When using "sparse_categorical_crossentropy" I am getting an error, that a value is 1 and therefore out of range [0, 1] when choosing "sparse_categorical_crossentropy" as loss function as it is proposed here: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/image_dataset_from_directory

When choosing "categorical_crossentropy" I don't get an accuracy nor loss. As the prices are float values for example 1.21 I can't figure out which label_mode to use. The model I use is a pretrained from keras with a different input and output layer:

```
resnet_model = Sequential()

pretrained_model = tf.keras.applications.ResNet50(include_top = False,
                                                  input_shape = (160, 160, 3),
                                                  pooling = "avg",
                                                  weights = "imagenet")

for layer in pretrained_model.layers:
    layer.trainable = False
    
resnet_model.add(pretrained_model)
resnet_model.add(Flatten())
resnet_model.add(Dense(512, activation="relu"))
resnet_model.add(Dense(1, activation="relu"))
```

EDIT: I've also tested the MSE as loss functiong with an sgd-optimizer however the loss value stays at "nan".

Would be so happy if anyone could help!

Comment: Use the option label_mode = None and shuffle=False and add your labels manually to `train_ds`

Comment: @AloneTogether my final dataset includes 70'000 datapoints therefore adding the labels manually won't be an option